# MongoDB with Scala language

Tags: json, mongodb, scala, mongo-scala-driver

i am new to MongoDB and Scala language

i am using scala language to connect mongodb locally

i am using below dependency

> //
> https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb.scala/mongo-scala-driver
>
> libraryDependencies += "org.mongodb.scala" %% "mongo-scala-driver" %
> "4.2.3"

what I tried

```
object Demo extends App {
  
  val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/")
  val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("DemoDB")
  println(database)

  val collection: MongoCollection[Document] =database.getCollection("demodata");
  val observable = collection.find();
}
```

the above code returning the data in below format

```
FindObservable(com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.internal.FindPublisherImpl@6253c26)
```

I also tried with

```
observable.subscribe ( new Observer[Document] {
  override def onNext(result: Document): Unit = println(result.toJson())
  override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println("Failed" + e.getMessage)
  override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Completed")
})
```

i also tried `printResult()` and `printHeadResult()` method also but none of the way is working

please help
thanks in advance

Comment: If you have the choice, I'd recommend having a look at [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongo Scala driver works in a non-blocking manner by returning `Observables` which need to be `Subsribed` on to consume the published data.

When you are subscribing to the `observable` like following,

```scala
object Demo extends App {
  
  val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/")
  val database: MongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("DemoDB")
  println(database)

  val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = database.getCollection("demodata")
  val observable = collection.find()

  observable.subscribe ( new Observer[Document] {
    override def onNext(result: Document): Unit = println(result.toJson())
    override def onError(e: Throwable): Unit = println("Failed" + e.getMessage)
    override def onComplete(): Unit = println("Completed")
  })
}
```

Your code does not wait for `observable` to actually publish anything, it just finishes right after subscribing. Hence you don't get anything.

You can either add a Something like a `Thread.sleep(5000)` at the end to block and give the `obeservable` some time to (hopefully finish and)  publish the data.

Or, you can add `val resultSeq = observable.collect` to block and collect all of published data in a single Sequence.

Comment: thanks, it works

,just some changes in my code is we have to give a complete of mongodb path to MongoClient like this

val mongoClient: MongoClient = MongoClient(" mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb")

Answer (score 0):

I found this link

it works for printResult() and printHeadResult() method

[Printing query results from Mongodb in Scala using mongo-scala-driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460472/printing-query-results-from-mongodb-in-scala-using-mongo-scala-driver)